How to set spring active profile in heroku for tomcat web application using webapprunner
I'm trying to create an existing project in Heroku. It's a tomcat-based web application that has environment-specific profiles. I want to select a profile based on the environment in Heroku. Is there any way to achieve this? I already tried the java option -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE, where $PROFILE is an environment variable but it didn't work. Here is my procfile
web: java -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war

Thanks
